# Finding and creating missing rows in table

Tags: postgresql

Hello postgres experts,

I have an app where users can vote on a poll. My schema looks like this:

`polls` table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Favorite fruit |

`options` table:

| id | poll_id | content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | apple |
| 2 | 1 | orange |
| 3 | 1 | grape |
| 4 | 1 | banana |

`participants` table:

| id | poll_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | John |
| 2 | 1 | Jane |

`votes` table:

| id | poll_id | participant_id | option_id | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | yes |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 3 | yes |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 2 | yes |

I made the poor choice of deciding to not create rows for "no" votes in the `votes` table thinking it would "save space". I realize now that it was not such a great idea because in the future I would like to know whether the user explicitly voted "no" or if perhaps the option was added after they voted and thus did not have the option to choose it. So I need to run a query that will fill all the missing "no" votes in the `votes` table for existing `participants`. The final result should look like this:

`votes` table:

| id | poll_id | participant_id | option_id | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | yes |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 3 | yes |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 2 | yes |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 2 | no |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 4 | no |
| 6 | 1 | 2 | 1 | no |
| 7 | 1 | 2 | 3 | no |
| 8 | 1 | 2 | 4 | no |

I have a dbfiddle with all the data already in it:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7d0f4c83095638cc6006b1d7876d0e01

**Side question:** Should I be concerned about the size of the votes table in this schema? I expect it to quickly blow up to millions of rows. Is a schema where `options` are stored as an array in the `polls` table and `votes` stored in the `participants` table a better idea?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What indices do you have on the tables? Especially `UNIQUE` ones

Comment: "*Should I be concerned about the size of the votes table in this schema?*" - this should probably be better asked as a separate question, maybe at [dba.SE]. Regardless: in general, no, you should no be concerned about millions of rows. Storing arrays won't save that much space, and make querying much more complicated. Whether it's a "better idea" depends a lot on what are you doing with these tables and what exactly you are optimising for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a [`JOIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN) of `participants` with `options`, [`EXCEPT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-union.html) the rows that already are in `votes`. There are various ways to do that, but most straightforward:

```
INSERT INTO votes(poll_id, participant_id, option_id, type)
SELECT poll_id, participant_id, option_id, 'no'
FROM (
  SELECT o.poll_id, p.id, o.id
  FROM options o
  JOIN participants p ON o.poll_id = p.poll_id
EXCEPT
  SELECT poll_id, participant_id, option_id
  FROM votes
) AS missing;
```

Alternatively:

```
INSERT INTO votes(poll_id, participant_id, option_id, type)
SELECT o.poll_id, p.id, o.id, 'no'
FROM options o
JOIN participants p ON o.poll_id = p.poll_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM votes
  WHERE poll_id = o.poll_id AND participant_id = p.id AND option_id = o.id
);
```

Or, assuming you already have `UNIQUE` index on `votes`, just

```
INSERT INTO votes(poll_id, participant_id, option_id, type)
SELECT o.poll_id, p.id, o.id, 'no'
FROM options o
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT votes_p_key
DO NOTHING;
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I think you summed up what I was trying to do really well. I managed to get all 3 working with some minor adjustments ("no -> 'no', adding column aliases).